# Get the `functionName` called from an ethereum transaction

Tags: ethereum, alchemy, etherscan

I'd like to display an ethereum transaction and include the `methodName` that was called. For example, this transaction's method was `mint`. Is there an API endpoint in etherscan or alchemy or infura that returns this information?

[Etherscan documentation](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/stats) for transactions doesn't include it. Neither does alchemy's `getTransactionReceipt` ([docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/apis/ethereum/eth_gettransactionreceipt)).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Etherscan and other blockchain explorers use their own custom key-value database of function selectors to their names that is **not available** through the site API, nor JSON RPC API (or its wrappers such as `web3` and `ethers.js`).

They have a collection of contract source codes and ABIs from the verification process, allowing them to translate a **function selector** available through the RPC method `getTransaction` field `data` (e.g. `0xa0712d68`) to a function definition (e.g. `mint(uint256)`), and then simply convert it to a human-readable format: `Mint`.

If you want to translate the function selector to a function name, you'll need to build your own dictionary, or use one of the few available online tools that have an already populated database, for example [this one](https://www.moesif.com/solidity-abi-hex-decoder/decode).